# Validation of xml configuration file for membrane-soa proxy

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, membrane-soa

Is there any api or xsd schema in membrane-soa proxy, which can be used to validate if created xml configuration file is valid, and it won't break working system?
The idea is that I wan to use set of scripts that will create this xml file, based on options provided to those scripts.
Thanks

Comment: http://membrane-soa.org/schemas/proxies-1.xsd?

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I need. Now I have to check if validation works on some example configuration

Comment: let me know if it does and whether I should post the link as an answer

Comment: yes, please add this as an answer. this xsd solved my problem. 
and to avoid duplicating posts, do you maybe know if they provide xml template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a Schema file for your needs located at

- http://membrane-soa.org/schemas/proxies-1.xsd

It's too long to include here, so sorry if this is a link only answer.

The company also maintains a GitHub repository at

- https://github.com/membrane

which you can search for more xsds or xml templates, etc.